# How to avoid MySQL Warning #1265. Data truncated for column..., when inserting empty string on list with default NULL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table defined as

```sql
CREATE TABLE `flagged` (
  `id` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag` ENUM('A','B') DEFAULT NULL
);
```

When executing

```
INSERT INTO `flagged` VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,NULL),(4,'');
```

I get the following warning:

```
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'flag' at row 4
```

Given that the data is result of a backup (a pretty large one), I cannot easily manipulate the INSERT commands.

I want to avoid reports of this particular case, but still get warnings of any other problem that might arise.

Comment: Empty string is not allowed by your `ENUM`. Maybe it's being crushed down to `NULL`?

Comment: **Silently** crushed down to `NULL` would be my expected behavior.
However it is neither silent nor crushed down to NULL but accepted. I suspect that the original database was allowing those empty not-NULL values and then it is causing these warnings.

Comment: MySQL used to do a lot of things silently in the past, but more recent versions have started to surface these things as warnings and errors. It depends on your server settings, and some defaults are being set to more strict. Many people have a lot of disdain for MySQL because it would silently do things like this, without warning, and end up trashing huge amounts of data. Better to be warned and ignore than never know what it was up to.

Comment: You could add an insert trigger to convert empty strings to null. Otherwise, you would have to add '' to the list of values for the enum, and do an update to change them to null.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql's enum data type can have [2 different empty (not null) value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html#enum-nulls):

1. An ordinary one listed in the allowed one (optional)
2. An error value indicating that an incorrect value was inserted into that field. This is an intrinsic behaviour of the enum data type.

The only way to distinguish between the two empty values is the index: the error empty value has the index 0; a regular value will have a non zero value.

In your case the ordinary enum list does not contain the empty value and the strict sql mode is turned off. Therefore, when you unsert an empty value onto the enum, mysql detects that it is not in the list. Since strict sql mode is turned off, mysql raises a warning only and the value is set to the error empty string (index 0). You can easily check this by converting the enum values to int in a query.

You have 2 options to get rid of these warning specifically. Both options have drawbacks, so you should carefully consider what you do. You may even decide to leave the warnings alone (that's what I would do).

1. Add the empty string to the enum's list. The drawback is that the index number of the empty value will change and may interfere with any sorting or filtering done on the enum field.
2. Use before insert trigger to convert blank values to null. Again, this may interfere with any sorting or filtering, and may also slow down the import process.

You must check how the blank values were handled in the source system and must evaluate if the application had any queries that would be affected by the chosen approach.